# Regex match all url except youtube ones

Tags: regex, c#-4.0, regex-negation

I am sure this is a trivial questions for you genii here. I seem to be stuck

I have a couple of links to process and I want to convert all links to hyperlinks and youtube links to youtube videos.

I have everything working. I just need to figure out how to regex out all links **EXCEPT** youtube ones.

Here is an example of my regex: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2u7g4

thanks.

Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the regex:

```
/(http:\/\/)?(www\.)?youtube.com\S*/
```

to match youtube links. Or did you mean you wanted to add on top of the regex you already have?

Edit: Oh, I'm dumb and wrote something super long, yeah, just negative lookahead at the beginning of your match:

```
(?!\S+youtube\.com)((?<!\S)(((f|ht){1}tp[s]?:\/\/|(?<!\S)www\.)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+))
```

http://regexr.com?2u7gg

Comment: I dont want to match youtube links, I want to negate them. i.e., select all links other than youtube ones.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to know when the link you matched was youtube so you can do something about it, my mistake, I'll edit.