# Regular expression for URL which not containing youtube

Tags: java, regex, url

I want to create a regular expresion which match with an URL except URl containing "youtube".

I have done this regexp which match with all URL:

```
(www+\.)?[\w-]+s{0,3}[/\.,;:!]{1,3}\s{0,3}(r[o0]|n[e3]t|lt|c[o0]m|[i!]nf[o0]|[o0]rg|b[i!][z2]|ru|[e3]du)(\/)?
```

But i want to add in the regular expresion, to not match if the URL containing 'youtube'.

We have a big system wich filter sentences that we received, and for each sentences received, we apply several regular expressions for example. And i want a regular expresion which say, this sentence containing an URL but not containing "youtube".

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it's possible, but a lot of headache. Why don't you use Java functions ?

Comment: Because i have the necessity to use a regexp ;-)

Comment: And why do you need to use a regex? You should say this in your question so that I don't jump off immediately saying "no, use `URI`" :p

Comment: We have a big system wich filter sentences that we received,
and for each sentences received, we apply severasl regular expressions for example.
And i want a regular expresion which say, this sentence containing an URL but not containing "youtube".

Comment: Is this system Java? If yes you can just have different filters, one of them using URI... Why limit yourself to regexes?

Comment: Because it's a huge system, and it's not a system that simply receuve the sentence and can apply the same regular expresion or test in all cases.
No it's more complicated.

SO the idea it's, i need a regular expresion which match which URL but not if URL containing youtube.
Is it really possible? :-)

Comment: Is this even an url lol ? I see a `\s` (whitespace o_o) ?

Comment: @superscral Can you provide what you want to match and what you don't want to match. As it currently stands, it doesn't make sense. Also are you matching this in a sentence? If not we may use `^$` which may make it more easier to code.

Comment: Yes, in a sentence, if there is a URL, which not containing www.youtube.com, then we don't want to match to this regexp.
The URl can be at the start, middle or end of the sentence.

Comment: @superscral I think Alex answer is what you're looking for. Also the regex you're using does look scary, I hope you know what you're doing ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this :

### Regex

```
(www+\.)?(?!youtube)([\w-]+s{0,3})[/\.,;:!]{1,3}\s{0,3}(r[o0]|n[e3]t|lt|c[o0]m|[i!]nf[o0]|[o0]rg|b[i!][z2]|ru|[e3]du)(\/)?
```

[image: Regular expression image]

### Test

```
youtube.com            => No Match
test.n3t               => Match
wwwwwww.coucous::.3du  => Match
utube;;; r0            => Match
```

Comment: Have you a tool which display the image that you put in your answer?

Comment: @superscral I use http://www.debuggex.com/ for generating the image. Just type in your regex and the image is generated on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regex for this, use [`URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html):

```
final URI uri = new URI(inputString);

// test against this URI's `.getHost()`, or `.getPath()`; whatever is relevant
```

Imprint this into your head using red iron/nitric acid(1): every time you have to do content checking of a URL or any URI in pure Java, use `URI`. Not regexes. URI will parse the thing for you.

Oh, and another thing: unlike `URL`, when compared with `.equals()`, *`URI` will not attempt to resolve the hostname*. This is no joke. Using URLs as keys into a map, or members of a set, is asking for trouble... Fortunately, `URL` has a `.toURI()` method.

(1) pick your choice

Comment: I have the necessity to use a regexp, i can't use another thing ;-)

Comment: OK, so, where do you NOT want to match `youtube`? In the host part, in the path part, in the query string part, in the fragment part?

Comment: i don't want to match with youtube in the host part of the query string, like www.youtube.com it's an URl but i don't want to match if it's an URL containing www.youtube.com but with others URL.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand a thing... Can you update your questions with examples you want to "negatively match"?

Comment: @fge OP is not trying to match against "conventionnal" URIs so using URI class here is useless.

Comment: @Alex what do you call "conventional" URIs? Every URL is a URI

Comment: @Alex Except this is not a valid URI, nor URL

Comment: Did you ever see an URI like this : `wwwwww.strange,,,   !nf0` ? OP expects the regexp to match this.

Comment: @fge From a OP point view it is an URL(or URI) but not the ones ("conventional") we (you and I) are used to.

Comment: @Alex again, THIS IS NOT A VALID URI. You may enter this in a browser's address bar, but the broswer will percent encode these. Try and build a `URI` with such a string, see it fail.

Comment: @fge I agree with you, those URI are not valid. IMO they are just presented in a disguised (encrypted?) form.

Answer (score 0):

A similar exclusion is mentioned here ([regex match urls NOT containing given set of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521366/regex-match-urls-not-containing-given-set-of-strings)) - just change your regex to have the negative look-ahead

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow ! Links to other answers (or websites) should be posted in the comment section, but since you're new you aren't able to. So if you want to post an answer, try to give a working example (for this situation) with some explanation (and maybe add "inspired by this answer").

Comment: This example concerning only htaccess, isn't it?

Comment: @Fabiotocchi You obviously have not meet me `:P`

Answer (score 0):

do you need a regex, assuming yourUrl is a string ...

```
!(yourUrl.contains("youtube"))
```

Comment: yes as I mentinned bellow, i need only a regular expression, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

here is the good example of "**Regex match all url except youtube ones**"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6681321/2413470

```
(?!\S+youtube\.com)((?<!\S)(((f|ht){1}tp[s]?:\/\/|(?<!\S)www\.)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+))
```

if this Regex is not usefull for you let me know